# Type checking key of nested mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have a type `FieldStrings` which is used to make a type matching the shape of an existing one, but with the second level fields changed to strings. In the example below, TypeScript gives an error:

[Example in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDOADnALYBcO+BycA5hFSAK5kBG0A3DQL48EI9eoSp5aRYAC8myVh258evXLgD0a5ABUAFinro4AG2ToYyMDuCELAT2IprFrAh1wQjC3rsPT5kBCEkAAmyDDAEEbBNmBYQVCg9Lhg9iioEVEAymAJHoQAPFoAfMgAvDjIANoACgCMyKDIANYQtmbaALpiVdUATA0gza3tWjW1HV1EOYnIvLM86pq6KCm+AO7oUE024QHIelArWGRwLUQsh3RGJuGR0XSXxIeEEOB0IKGWKAn0OmA+EAAdLgEOgQEEwhlgtlciIqOk7jDEgUMOgSuVxERSJRqBIGLIAEQwTAEgA0fHJgmEolxtEI0kJ7DgUDJFNw-FUMBYIAQYGAYLCtXyAGlkBAAB6QD42Fptcyo0loMWS173WXtVGVYUdIoAChoxPQ8MwlOaVGFppg8NwAEoqAA3dDAUKYowQf63KIANWMLBQ5UNlSaHUqMA6AmQbo9UKRHjKkMR0zyQZDYYjoPB6DdgKM6Hous9wR9Rj9isLsfoNuUqgzEMNxqwGJoJHI3XxVH6vFNQjhFXpMio9S77IWMFqBZNyAJPcIZKn-YgBKruCAA)

```js
interface Foo {
  spam: {
    age: number;
  };
  eggs: {
    size: number;
  };
}

// The goal of this type is to change the type of nested fields to string
type FieldStrings<T> = { [P1 in keyof T]: { [P2 in keyof T[P1]]: string } };

// The type works fine here to make sure all fields are present and the right type.
const fieldStrings: FieldStrings<Foo> = {
  spam: {
    age: "foo",
  },
  eggs: {
    size: "bar",
  },
};

function f1<K extends keyof Foo, F extends keyof Foo[K]>(
  foo: Foo,
  k: K,
  f: F
): void {
  let fieldValue = foo[k][f];
  let fieldString = fieldStrings[k][f]; // <----- Type 'F' cannot be used to index type 'FieldStrings<Foo>[K]'.
  console.log(fieldValue, fieldString);
}

const foo: Foo = {
  spam: { age: 2 },
  eggs: { size: 1 },
};

f1(foo, "eggs", "size");
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make this type check succeed?

Comment: What kind of operation do you want to perfom with ```fieldStrings[k][f]```? In current implementation ```f1``` function looks useless.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in TS 4.6+ with [indexed access improvements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#indexed-access-inference-improvements).

In TS 4.5 and older, you could've used an assertion (a bit ew), or have changed the signature of the function (in this case I found that an intersection worked):

```
function f1<K extends keyof Foo, F extends keyof FieldStrings<Foo>[K] & keyof Foo[K]>(
```

[Playground (TS v4.5.5)](https://tsplay.dev/mx8zZm)